# Turtlebot moving circles with map

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys ,

I try to move my turtlebot with a map. I finished my example where i give a point to my bot. After he got the point he moves to the point but he drive in circles. When i start the script two times he moves correctly most of the time.

Can somebody help me?

I use Ros Kinetic with Gazebo 7.0. First of all i start gazebo:

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

after this i load the map:

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch

After this i use a script to move to a point or a bunch of points with my robot. Sometimes the robot drives in the direction of the point but he circles around while he moves. He rotates around 360 degree drives a bit further then he stop and rotates again. Most of the time i need to restart the script and he drives straight to the point without any circles.

I used  this script as a foundation for my purpose:

https://github.com/markwsilliman/turtlebot/blob/master/go_to_specific_point_on_map.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272603/turtlebot-moving-circles-with-map/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-09**:
Please edit your question to provide more information. A video of the behavior would be preferable, as well as a full description of how to reproduce your problem. See http://wiki.ros.org/Support for guidelines on asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a common behavior if the robot gets close to the goal, but is just outside it's tolerance. So it drives in a small circle to try to get closer to the goal position than it's current pose.

There's a guide for tuning the navigation stack here with links to several other resources: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide

You probably want to slightly increase the tolerance for the goals so that the robot doesn't continue to hunt once it gets there.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2017-10-11**:
Okay , then i need to improve the navigation stack and optimize it. Thank u for your help.